# Convert php data to Json

Tags: php, json

I'm a newbie to php. I'm working on fetching the result from the DB and to send those details in the format of Json to the ajax call. Whereas I'm not able to convert using json_encode. 
I'd like to get the result in the format of

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Rafael","password":"rafael"},{"id":1,"name":"nadal","password":"nadal"}]
```

My php code is

```
// credentials of MySql database.
$username = "root";
$password = "admin";
$hostname = "localhost"; 

$jsonArray = array();
//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

$selected = mysql_select_db("Angular",$dbhandle)
or die("Could not select Angular");
//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name,password FROM User");

//fetch tha data from the database  
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $id = $row{'id'};
    $name = $row{'name'};
    $password = $row{'password'};
    $jsonData = json_encode($name,$password);
}
echo "Json:".$jsonData;
```

Comment: What is the output of your current method?

Comment: I got it.  //fetch tha data from the database 
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  
  $id = $row{'id'};
  $name = $row{'name'};
  $password = $row{'password'};
     $data[] = array('id' => $id, 'name' => $name, 'password' => $password);
 }
 $json = json_encode($data);
 echo "Json data:".$json;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code after `mysql_query` to:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{

  $jsonArray[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($jsonArray);
```

Note that you do not select the ID in the query. it should be

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, password FROM User");
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameters within a json_encode must be an array.

You should use

```
$jsonData = json_encode( $array ); //$array is your array element
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Something like this

$queryString = "SELECT * FROM user";

$query = mysql_query($queryString) or die(mysql_error());

```
$db = array();
while($dbs = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $db[] = $dbs;
}

echo 

$output = json_encode(array(
    "success" => mysql_errno() == 0,

    "information" => $db
));
```

myoutput will be look like this;

it will display all the fields in your databasetable

{"success":true,"information":[{"id":"1","username":"sampleName","LastName":"SampleLastName"}]
}

Hope it works :D